# Do any Oracle .NET connectors provide the line number of SQL errors?

Tags: .net, oracle

If I type a SQL statement into SQLPlus and there is an error, SQLPlus will tell you what the ORA error code is and the line number and position of the error like this example:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from schema.table
  3  where column = 0;
from schema.table
            *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

If I connect using a .NET Oracle provider and there is an error, I would expect the Line Number to be contained somewhere in the Exception, or one of the Inner Exceptions, but I cannot find it.  Does anyone know if there is a way to get this information when in .NET?

*(The project I am working on uses System.Data.OracleClient from the 4.0 Framework, but I may be able to modify that if needed)*

Comment: Could you not trap the error and log it in the database end? You're likely to get better information that way.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this using that client - I went through the native APIs underneath, and they don't seem to have a way of getting the error line. Either SQLPlus (and SQL Developer) don't use OCI as their API, or they are injecting some extra code to trap the errors and report them separately. I'd just convert to ODP.NET if that's possible for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle provider ODP.NET shows the line numbers.

Comment: I swapped the provider over to ODP.NET and caught the OracleException and I examined it and the attached list of OracleErrors.  I didn't find the line number anywhere in the Exception.  Where do I need to look to get the line number?

Comment: In the stack trace you will find lines like this: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-XXX : ... error ORA-XXX: at line Y

Comment: I searched through all of the stack trace lines and could not find any mention of the ORA error number nor the line number.  Perhaps I'm using a different version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.